# How can we make clusters of rows of 3 dimensional matrix using knnsearch?

Tags: matlab

Here is a subset of a 988x3 matrix (vertices of a 3D object):

1. 2 3 4
2. 1 2 3
3. 8 5 2
4. 6 2 4
5. 7 8 9
6. 9 5 1
7. 3 5 8
8. 6 5 7
9. 1 2 8
10. . . .

Let suppose the 7 nearest neighbors of the first vertex are v(2), v(20), v(5), v(15), v(19), v(50), and v(23). We choose another vertex and find its 7 nearest neighbors according to this condition: The new vertex and its 7 nearest neighbors should not be from the last chosen nearest neighbors. I short, I want to make clusters of 8 distinct vertices from a list of 988 vertices based on the knnsearch. how can we do it in MATLAB?

Comment: This is a more involved task than merely doing a clustering, as what you are asking for is each cluster have an exact fixed size. To get an initial approximate result, you could try running `kmeans` with as many clusters as required, but will not be guaranteed to have 8 elements each.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it depends on the total number of vertices. The last cluster may have less than 8 vertices, which is ok for me.

Comment: It is not about just the last group (or that the number of vertices is not an exact multiple of 8). It is about the cost function, which for k-means is not dependent on the number of points in each cluster, just their pairing/location. You could have empty clusters and also clusters with few or many elements.

Comment: `knnsearch` using `kdtree` is very different from `kmeans clustering`. They both have a k in them, but that's about it.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the distance between the neighbors and the center of the neighborhood? You say you want k nearest neighbors, but is there some limit on the sum of distances of vertices to their center? (If not, then you can just choose random centers and random neighbors, so I assume there must be some metric.)

Comment: @beaker there is no restriction on the distances of the neighbors from its centers. I agree with you that we can select some random centers and find their nearest neighbors. Actually, I want to use clusters for secret data embedding (watermark), so random center selection may give me fewer clusters for data embedding, where as I need more clusters to improve embedding capacity.

Comment: If there is no restriction then you can simply partition the nodes randomly into 988/8 "neighborhoods". But I suspect that's not what you want, so let me ask my question in another way. Say you select centers and neighbors for all 988 nodes. That's `partition 1`. Now you generate a different partition, `partition 2`. How do you tell whether `partition 1` or `partition 2` is better for your purposes?

Comment: @beaker the only parameter that can tell us that partition 1 or partition 2 is better is the distance from the center vertex. random selection could select vertices that may overlap with other clusters or their distances from the center may not be minimum distances. If we could select centers the way I have asked in my question, then neighbors will be selected based on minimum distances from the centers and the issue of overlapping may also be solved.

Comment: If you choose the vertices as you say, you are not guaranteed that the sum of distances between vertices and their centers is minimum, and you won't be guaranteed that clusters will not overlap. You didn't anything about keeping the distance minimum, and since your approach and the current answer don't enforce this, I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kd-trees](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21512-ataiya-kdtree) could help here.
It has a function called `kdtree_k_nearest_neighbors`. 
In pseudocode

```
construct kd-tree
Pick random point 
find k-nearest neighbors
store indices
remove point and k-nearest neighbors from set
*repeat*
```